# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socker

Tags: mysql

I am using Ubuntu 20.4. LTS version.

I sucessfully installed mysql server with

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Than I checked

```
mysql --version
```

and it says: *mysql  Ver 8.0.31 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)*

Than I wanted to install secure installation with
`sudo mysql_secure_installation`
and it says :

**Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

I amd completely lost and I have not idea what to do..

Comment: Please check service status via
```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

Comment: Are you sure mysql runs?  Could yo edit your question with the output of `systemctl status mysql`?